# How to map entity primary key to Spark ML predictions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I trained a Spark ML model, scored my holdout dataset with it, and now need to look up the prediction for specific entities.

How can I figure out which prediction is for whom? Is there a way I can add the entity primary key (e.g. Member_ID) to my prediction output?

More specifically: to score the dataset, I used:
`predictions = trained_model.transform(holdout_data)`

It produces a dataframe with columns: "features", "label", "prediction" 
(label is the response variable)

How do I find out the corresponding Member_ID for each prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `holdout_data` only contain the columns: `["features", "label"]`? If so then add the `Member_ID` to it.

The `.transform()` method of the `pyspark.ml` model *adds* the extra column `prediction` to the `holdout_data`, so if `Member_ID` is there to begin with, then problem solved.

Comment: Thanks, it works. It's good to know how `.transform()` method of the `pyspark.ml` works, I thought it only takes in "features" and "label" columns, so didn't include things like primary keys.

Comment: No problem. True, I assumed the same.